# In a Mongo collection, how do you query for a specific object in an array?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve an object from an array in mongodb.  Below is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e9b43968425b29ecc87ffd"),
    "firstname" : "john",
    "lastname" : "smith",
    "trips" : [ 
        {
            "submitted" : 1407824585356,
            "tripCategory" : "staff",
            "tripID" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "tripID" : "2",
            "tripCategory" : "volunteer"
        }, 
        {
            "tripID" : "3",
            "tripCategory" : "individual"
        }
    ]
}
```

My ultimate goal is to update only when trips.submitted is absent so I thought I could query and determine what the mongo find behavior would look like
if I used the $and query operator.  So I try this:

```
db.users.find({
    $and: [
      { "trips.tripID": "1" },
      { "trips": { $elemMatch: { submitted: { $exists: true } } } }
    ]
  },
  { "trips.$" : 1 }   //projection limits to the FIRST matching element
)
```

and I get this back:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e9b43968425b29ecc87ffd"),
    "trips" : [ 
        {
            "submitted" : 1407824585356,
            "tripCategory" : "staff",
            "tripID" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Great.  This is what I want.  *However, when I run this query*:

```
db.users.find({
    $and: [
      { "trips.tripID": "2" },
      { "trips": { $elemMatch: { submitted: { $exists: true } } } }
    ]
  },
  { "trips.$" : 1 }   //projection limits to the FIRST matching element
)
```

I get the same result as the first!  So I know there's something odd about my query that isn't correct.  But I dont know what.  The only thing I've changed between the queries is **"trips.tripID" : "2"**, which in my head, should have prompted mongo to return no results.  What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the array is in a specific order you can refer to a specific index in the array like this:-

```
db.trips.find({"trips.0.submitted" : {$exists:true}})
```

Or you could simply element match on both values:

```
db.trips.find({"trips" : {$elemMatch : {"tripID" : "1", 
                                        "submitted" : {$exists:true}
              }}})
```

Your query, by contrast, is looking for a *document* where both are true, not an element within the trips field that holds for both.

Answer (score 1):

The output for your query is correct. Your query asks mongo to return a document which has the given *tripId* and the field *submitted* within its *trips* array. The document you have provided in your question satisfies both conditions for both *tripIds*. You are getting the first element in the array *trips* because of your projection.

I have assumed you will be filtering records by the person's name and then retrieving the elements inside *trips* based on the field-exists criteria. The output you are expecting can be obtained using the following:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        {$match: 
            {
                "firstname" : "john",
                "lastname" : "smith"
            }
        },
        {$unwind: "$trips"},
        {$match:
             { 
                 "trips.tripID": "1" ,
                 "trips.submitted": { $exists: true }
             }
        }
    ]
)
```

The aggregation pipeline works as follows. The first `$match` operator filters one document (in this case the document for *john smith*) The `$unwind` operator in mongodb aggregation unwinds the specified array (*trips* in this case), in effect denormalizing the sub-records associated with the parent records. The second `$match` operator filters the denormalized/unwound documents further to obtain the one required as per your query.